# Best Practice -- Unit test dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, junit

This is a best practice question.

I'm maintaining a web application which is a proxy around another web application whose source code I do not have access to. My project's function is to make the other server's API easy to use and mobile friendly.

I'm in the process of adding unit tests and I find myself wanting to break standard best practices like `Tests should be independent`.

To test `login`, I first need to `register`. If `register` fails, `login` would fail (or be pointless.) What is the best way to handle this? Using a `setUp` function to register and then fail `login` because the expected user is missing? Or enforce strict test ordering and make sure `register` is called first?

I tend to lean towards using a `setUp` function, but I'd be curious to know what the community thinks.

The test framework is JUnit, although I imagine this question would apply to other frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing integration tests, not unit tests.  Unit tests simulate dependencies and exercise a single class.  It's not necessary to register first because you mock the results of a successful registration (if necessary, depending on your class design).

For the integration tests, yes, you would have a complicated setup.  If that's too slow to run each time, you may find it easier to create a single test that performs a number of tests each dependent on the previous tests.